# How to hide keyboard of entry inside the listview in xamarin.forms.ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uikeyboard

How to hide keyboard of an entry.I have an entry inside of a listview. When I tap on the entry the keyboard is showing, but the keyboard is not hiding when I tap outside. The listview row is adding dynamically so in first case only one row is in it.Android is working perfectly. But in iOS this issue is there.

Please help me

```
<ListView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="_list"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                   <StackLayout Orientation=Horizontal>
                       <Label Text="Name"/>
                       <Entry PlaceHolder="Name" />
                       <Label Text="+" FontSize="50">
                            <Label .GestureRecognizers>
                               <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="AddMore_Tapped" 
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Id}"/>
                            </Label .GestureRecognizers>
                       </Label>
                   </StackLayout>
                       </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Xaml.CS

```
           private async void AddMore_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {
               _list.Add("1");
              }
```

here is my code,

first time only one row is there after clicking the "+" icon one row will be added to listview. So in the case of listview with one row, when I tap on that entry the keyboard is showing, but when I tap outside it's not hiding.It's hiding only when I tap on the first row.

Comment: You could use Custom Renderer to hide the keyboard of ios. Check the article. https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/05/19/a-keyboard-disabled-entry-control-in-xamarin-forms/ You could download the source file from the GitHub.https://github.com/UdaraAlwis/Xamarin-Playground/tree/master/XFNoSoftKeyboadEntryControl

Comment: I tried with this one , but in this case the keyboard is not displaying always. I want to hide this when I tap on the outside .

Comment: My code could not reproduce, could you provide the code about how do you add row dynamically?

Comment: Updated my code...,I am using forms version 2.3

Answer (score 0):

You could update your Xamarin.forms version to the last.

In ios, the keyboard would hide when you click on the other place of listview except the “+” label.

[image]

Or you could use custom renderer to make the done button, to hide the keyboard manually.

CustomEntry:cs

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry
{

}
```

CustomEntryRenderer.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace HidekeyboardOfEntryDemo.iOS
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        private UITextField textField;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            textField = (UITextField)this.Control;
            textField.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
<hidekeyboardofentrydemo:CustomEntry Placeholder="Name" />
```

You could download HidekeyboardOfEntryDemo project from GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git